# Shopify reCaptcha V2 align to right cant select images or buttons

Tags: shopify, recaptcha, captcha

In tried to align a V2 Captcha in my Shopify store but couldn't.
Tried this code but nothing. This only happens in mobile.

[Mobile view of the image challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDFBe.png)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   // Verificar si existe el atributo g-recaptcha-response   if ($("#g-recaptcha-response").length \> 0) {     // Modificar el estilo del elemento padre del elemento con el atributo g-recaptcha-response     $("#g-recaptcha-response").closest("div").css("left", "5px");   } });
```